# How to create Vertically scrolling PageView in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, flutter, dart

PageView by default has horizontal scrolling in flutter, but I need to create a vertically scrollable Pages through PageView, any solution ??

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-pageview-in-flutter-with-custom-transitions-581d9ea6dded). There seems to be a guide to transition for vertical PageView.

Comment: **Please check this maybe this one helps you** https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper

Answer (score 14):

Use `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical`

```
PageView(
    controller: pageViewController,
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    children: [Page1(), Page2()],
)
```

Comment: @AskNilesh , even after adding scroll direction vertical my pageview is scrolling horizontally. I don't understand why!!
P.S.: I am using pageView.builder()

Comment: I have this app with tik tok pr Instagram reels like UI/UX, currently, I am using TabView to achieve vertical scrolling but it's not good in terms of performance.